# Scrapy not able to crawl next page

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have been trying a lot but I am unable to make scrapy crawl to the next page and extract the products.

```
class SpecialOffersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'special_offers'
    allowed_domains = ['www.cigabuy.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.cigabuy.com/crazy-sales-c-56.html']

    def parse(self, response):
        for product in response.xpath("//div[@class='p_box_wrapper']/div"):
            yield {
                'title': product.xpath(".//a[@class='p_box_title']/text()").get(),
                'url': product.xpath(".//a[@class='p_box_title']/@href").get(),
                'discounted_price':  product.xpath(".//div[@class='p_box_price cf']/span[1]/text()").get(),
                'original_price': product.xpath(".//div[@class='p_box_price cf']/span[2]/text()").get() if product.xpath(".//div[@class='p_box_price cf']/span").get() is not None else product.xpath(".//div[@class='p_box_price cf']/text()").get(),
                'next_page': response.xpath("//a[@class='nextPage']/@href").get()

            }

        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='nextPage']/@href").get()

        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass user-agent while making requests. Otherwise, website keeps returning first page data.

**Modified Code**

```
import scrapy

class SpecialOffersSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['www.cigabuy.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.cigabuy.com/crazy-sales-c-56.html']
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36'}

    def parse(self, response):

        for product in response.xpath("//div[@class='p_box_wrapper']/div"):
            yield {
                'title': product.xpath(".//a[@class='p_box_title']/text()").get(),
                'url': product.xpath(".//a[@class='p_box_title']/@href").get(),
                'discounted_price':  product.xpath(".//div[@class='p_box_price cf']/span[1]/text()").get(),
                'original_price': product.xpath(".//div[@class='p_box_price cf']/span[2]/text()").get() if product.xpath(".//div[@class='p_box_price cf']/span").get() is not None else product.xpath(".//div[@class='p_box_price cf']/text()").get(),
                'next_page': response.xpath("//a[@class='nextPage']/@href").get()

            }

        next_page = response.xpath("//a[@class='nextPage']/@href").get()

        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page, callback=self.parse, headers=self.headers)
```

Comment: I tried the same but it didn't work. Still, the output is first page data only.

Comment: Have you tried to run your modified code that I posted bcoz for me it's returning each page data.

Comment: After changing ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False it works.

Comment: I was getting the error before and after the using your modified code. The error is 2021-07-14 22:17:13 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://www.cigabuy.com/crazy-sales-c-56-pg-2.html?disp_order=18>

Comment: It has nothing to do with the code rather it's your settings regarding robots.txt rule & changing it to false tells spider not to obey the rule of website. I hope it helps, would you mind to accept the answer?